# Get the next lowest ID or the greatest?

Tags: mysql

This is the SQL I have so far:

```
  SELECT  `cimg`.*,
          `pimg`.`id` as `prev`,
          `nimg`.`id` as `next`
  FROM    `images` as `cimg`,
          `images` as `pimg`,
          `images` as `nimg`
  WHERE   `cimg`.`id` = :id AND
          `pimg`.`id` = (
            SELECT  max(`id`)
            FROM    `images`
            WHERE   `id` < :id
          ) AND
          `nimg`.`id` = (
            SELECT  min(`id`)
            FROM    `images`
            WHERE   `id` > :id
          )
```

It basically selects all of the data from a row, then selects the `id` of the row above it and below it.

However when the current row is one of the extremes, I need it to then get the `id` of the other extreme for its `prev` (if it is the lowest) or `next` (if it is the greatest).

Kind of like a carousel or loop. E.g. we have a table with `id`'s 2, 5, 10, 20 and 53.

If it was the lowest row as current row, we would return all of the data for the row with `id 2` and additionally two more columns; `53` as `prev` and `5` as `next`.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Aren't the last two sentences of my question exactly that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you'd want to do is check if there is a value or not. When there is no value in your subquery it should return the `MAX()` or `MIN()` value of `id`.

Not sure whether this is the best option but it should do the trick.

```
SELECT 
    `cimg`.*, `pimg`.`id` AS `prev`, `nimg`.`id` AS `next`
FROM
    `images` AS `cimg`,
    `images` AS `pimg`,
    `images` AS `nimg`
WHERE
    `cimg`.`id` = :id
AND `pimg`.`id` = 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `images` WHERE `id` < :id) IS NOT NULL 
        THEN (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `images` WHERE `id` < :id)
        ELSE (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `images`)
    END 
AND `nimg`.`id` = 
    CASE  WHEN (SELECT  MIN(`id`) FROM `images` WHERE `id` > :id) IS NOT NULL
        THEN (SELECT  MIN(`id`) FROM `images` WHERE `id` > :id)
        ELSE (SELECT  MIN(`id`) FROM `images`)
    END
;
```